# Different time zones to UTC time zone conversion

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, xslt-grouping

Need to convert to UTC time zone from this time zones [AFGHAN , RUS02 , UT+103 , UTC+1 , UTC+10 , UTC+43 ,WAT , PST , IST and CST ]

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#timezone.functions

Comment: P.S. What on earth is UTC+43? Is it on Earth?